# Flash OS firmware on an OS corrupted device via TWRP

Tags: device-firmware, operating-system, android-tv

I have a big issue: I got 2 units of the Android TV device called "Stream+" sold by Channel Master, manifactured by Technicolor (https://www.channelmaster.com/Stream_OTA_DVR_p/cm-7600.htm)

One is perfectly working.
The other one has the OS files completely corrupted and does not even allow me to complete a factory reset successfully (and that's out of warrancy as well, so I have to fix by myself).
All it does when is switched on is showing a welcome logo, then attempts to load the OS but stays stuck forever, freezed in a black screen.

The following is the menu with the options shown when I load it on recovery mode: https://images2.imgbox.com/c9/0e/E947NI4Z_o.jpg

What I want to ask is...
Can I use TWRP to flash a copy of the OS Firmware from the device 1 (the fully working one) and then flash the defective one with it?
Defective one, as said, DOES NOT load the OS, all I can do is using one of the options shown in the above pic.

Have I got any chances to solve this through TWRP? (Or anything else)

Comment: First question is: Does a TWRP build for your device exist? If not, the answer is a clear no for TWRP of course. You could *flash* a ROM via that recovery (at least the official one, if the manufacturer offers the images) via ADB or USB. You could even perform a factory reset from there ("Wipe data"). I'd at least try first whether "wipe cache" helps; sometimes a broken file in cache has the strangest effects.

Comment: No idea if a TWRP build for my device exists, i doubt it does. That's why i asked if i can create one from my working device. As for your advice regarding factory reset wipe data and wipe cache, tried already but it still doesnt solve my problem, system boots, shows logo, then gets freezed on black screen forever (after goes in freeze status, even all buttons like reset etc get freezed, forcing me to unplug the device from AC).

Comment: There is a "TWRP builder" somewhere. I've never tried it, so I can neither tell what is needed to use it nor how it works. AFAIR it analyses your stock recovery and builds based on that.

Comment: I've just found its own firmware. It's a .tlayer file tho. Never saw such extension before. Any idea how to flash it to the device? Put the .tlayer file in a usb external drive doesn't work. Does probably require to be inserted in a folder renamed 'update'? Or maybe other files are missing...no idea...

Comment: Me neither. Should be some info where you found that image, or in the manufacturers forums.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.androidcentral.com/10-basic-terminal-commands-you-should-know
this is a starting point to flash twrp or a custom rom using the Android Debug Bridge  ADB

Look for a utube how to install ADB and fastboot for your pc . Then when u have adb command window open connect usb to device & use
 1. The adb devices command  which is    "adb devices"

do this first before down loading any of the sdk package as you need to know if your pc can recognize your device.

you could also use somthing like this for the type of device you have this only works for samsung but there are others for different manufactures

https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjz65GBkaneAhWlhKYKHaTHBuQQwqsBMAN6BAgDEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJv538rOL5p0&usg=AOvVaw3bIUhWGgbgikQiD3eBUfG1

hope this points you in right direction

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious reply, but it lacks the first needed part: how am I supposed to create an exact image of my working device, and then, how can I flash the defective device which can't be booted so I cant grant usb debug access nor install TWRP?